# IOS stackview addArrangedSubview add at specific index

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

How is it possible to add a arranged subview in a particular index in a UIStackView?

something like:

```
stackView.addArrangedSubview(nibView, atIndex: index)
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You mean you want to insert, not add:

```
func insertArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView, atIndex stackIndex: Int)
```

Comment: I am adding labels as subview
what happens is that if I keep Stackview axis horizontal, I get one horizontal strip of UILabels
if I keep it vertical, I get a vertical strip of UILabels
where labels are arranged one below the other
its arranged like this
label1
label2
label3
and so on
But what I am trying to achieve is this
label1, label2(if it fits) otherwise take it below
label3, label4
label5 and so on

Comment: @Ranjit for your requirement, maybe you should try collectionview instead.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to struggle with the index you can use this extension

```swift
extension UIStackView {
    func insertArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView, belowArrangedSubview subview: UIView) {
        arrangedSubviews.enumerated().forEach {
            if $0.1 == subview {
                insertArrangedSubview(view, at: $0.0 + 1)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func insertArrangedSubview(_ view: UIView, aboveArrangedSubview subview: UIView) {
        arrangedSubviews.enumerated().forEach {
            if $0.1 == subview {
                insertArrangedSubview(view, at: $0.0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```